# Scheduling jobs on postgres

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to send reminder mails according to epoch time saved in database.
How can I do that.
I am using Java and Postgresql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a cron job (or the equivalent in Windows)

Answer (score 1):

You only need setup pgAgent for postgresql

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/pgagent.html